# Is there any way to retrieve area report for a google adword campaign using awql?

Tags: php, google-ads-api, awql

I am trying to get a report for my campaign where I need the impressions and clicks for each area for my campaign.

I tried all fields in `GEO_PERFORMANCE_REPORT` but it doesn't retrieve the area.

I also tried to get data from `CAMPAIGN_LOCATION_TARGET_REPORT` but still can not have the area.

any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i will answer. 

Unfortunately, the fields for city will be always retrieved as IDs if you use *AWQL*.
 
So, you will have workaround to get the city or country name where you should download 
  [city (Cities-DMA Regions)](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/geotargeting#dma)  
and 
  [country (Geographical Targeting)](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/geotargeting)  
 codes as .csv file.
You then could store it in your database and get the *city/country* names by querying your database when needed.